# I am working on a program that takes a voice recording from the user and translates it into text through whisper

Tags: python, tkinter, audio-recording, chatgpt-api, openai-whisper

```
import os 
import wave
import time
import threading
import tkinter as tk
import pyaudio
import openai
import whisper



class VoiceRecoder:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root=tk.Tk()
        self.canvas =tk.Canvas(self.root, height=450, width=750, bg="#add8e6")
        self.canvas.pack()

        self.frame1 = tk.Frame(self.root, bg="#add8e6")
        self.frame1.place(relx=0.0, rely=0.0, relwidth=1, relheight=0.2)

        self.frame_alt = tk.Frame(self.root, bg="#add8e6")
        self.frame_alt.place(relx=0.51, rely=0.21, relwidth=0.48, relheight=0.5)
        
        self.frame_alt2 = tk.Frame(self.root, bg="#add8e6")
        self.frame_alt2.place(relx=0.01, rely=0.21, relwidth=0.48, relheight=0.5)

        self.label1 = tk.Label(self.frame_alt, text="Meeting Text:", font="Verdana 12 bold", background="#add8e6")
        self.label1.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
        
        self.text_area = tk.Text(self.frame_alt, height=10, width=45)
        self.text_area.tag_configure('style', foreground='#bfbfbf', font=('verdana', 7, 'bold'))
        self.text_area.pack()

        self.label2 = tk.Label(self.frame_alt2, text="Summary of Meeting Text:", font="Verdana 12 bold", background="#add8e6")
        self.label2.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
        
        self.text_area2 = tk.Text(self.frame_alt2, height=10, width=45)
        self.text_area2.pack()

        self.button = tk.Button(self.frame1, text="", font=("Arial", 20, "bold"), command=self.click_handler)
        self.button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.8,anchor="center")
        
        self.button =tk.Button(self.frame1,text="convert record",command=self.start_recording)
        self.button.pack()
        
        self.label = tk.Label(self.frame1, text="00:00:00")
        self.label.pack()
        self.recording=False
        self.root.mainloop()
    
   
    def click_handler(self): 
        if self.recording:
            self.recording=False
            self.button.config(fg="black")
        else:
            self.recording=True
            self.button.config(fg="red")
            threading.Thread(target=self.record).start()
    
    def record(self):
        audio=pyaudio.PyAudio()
        stream=audio.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,channels=1,rate=44100,input=True,frames_per_buffer=1024)
        frames=[]
        
        start=time.time()
        
        while self.recording:
            data=stream.read(1024)
            frames.append(data)
            
            passed=time.time() -start
            secs=passed %60
            mins=passed//60
            hours=mins//60
            self.label.config(text=f"{int(hours):02d}:{int(mins):02d}:{int(secs):02d}")
        
        stream.stop_stream()
        stream.close()
        audio.terminate()
        
        exists= True
        i=1
        while exists:
            if os.path.exists(f"recording{i}.wav"):
                i+=1
            else:
                exists = False       
        
        sound_file= wave.open(f"recording{i}.wav","wb")
        sound_file.setnchannels(1)
        sound_file.setsampwidth(audio.get_sample_size(pyaudio.paInt16))
        sound_file.setframerate(44100)
        sound_file.writeframes(b"".join(frames))
        sound_file.close()
        return sound_file
    
    
    def summarize_text(self, text):
        response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
        model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
        messages=[
                {"role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful assistant."},
                {"role": "user", "content": f"summarize the text: {text}"}
            ]
        )
        text_summary = response.choices[0].message.content
        return text_summary

    def start_recording(self):
        record = self.record()
        
        model = whisper.load_model("large")
        result = model.transcribe(record)
        self.text_area.insert("end", result["text"])
        
        text_summary1 = self.summarize_text(result["text"])
        self.text_area2.insert("end", text_summary1)
     
    
VoiceRecoder()
```

I get an error like this:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\pyauio_deneme\as1.py", line 114, in start_recording
    result = model.transcribe(record)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\whisper\transcribe.py", line 121, in transcribe    mel = log_mel_spectrogram(audio, padding=N_SAMPLES)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\whisper\audio.py", line 131, in log_mel_spectrogram
    audio = torch.from_numpy(audio)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: expected np.ndarray (got Wave_write)
```

I think whisper doesn't see the audio file.How can I solve this problem ?

I have tried many things but I can't solve the problem.When you press the microphone button, the recording starts, when you press it again, it stops the recording, and on the convert record button, you call the start_recording function. I tried to see the text in the interface but it didn't work.

Comment: You `open` your wave file in "write only mode", put your recording in and `close` it again. By the time you return `sound_file` from the `record` function, it is an unusuable instance (see [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/wave.html#wave.Wave_write) of a `Wave_write` object. You have to rethink what you actually want to return, or you have to reload the data from the saved file in "read only mode".